# LINQ ,cómo obtener el valor Max ID y sumarle +1 en cada compra

Tags: c#, dataset

Estoy trabajando en C# con Dataset , el problema que tengo es el de obtener el valor máximo del campo `ID` de una determinada tabla y sumarle `1`

Para mostrarlo en un `TextBox`, el `TextBox` al que quiero mostrarlo en el formulario es el correlativo, en la base de datos el campo correlativo lo vincule con el campo ID lo maneje de esta manera

```
(right('0000000'+CONVERT([varchar](7),[IDVenta]),(7)))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

,al sumarle `1` quiero obtener el numero que se le asignara cada que guardo la venta mostrándolo en el `TextBox` con LINQ o alguna otra forma de resolverlo .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
txtCorrelativo.Text = string.Format("{0:0000000}",  );
```

Comment: ¿Cuál de todos los `ID`? En la captura de pantalla que muestras veo cuatro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que tus datos están en una[`DataTable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2), puedes leer sus filas con:

```
dataTable.Rows
```

Usando LinQ puedes quedarte con el `ID` que te interese mediante [`Select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
// Todos los IDVenta de la tabla:
var idventas = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row.Field<int>("IDVenta"));
```

Si lo que quieres, es el mayor de ellos, usa [`Max`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
// El mayor IDVenta de la tabla:
var maxidventa = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row.Field<int>("IDVenta")).Max();
```

Y ya está, puedes sumarle `1`:

```
// Siguiente IDVenta
var siguienteID = maxidventa + 1;
```